# Testing for missing required char fields

Tags: django, testing

I'm trying to understand why the following test does not fail. In this simplified example there is a required field 'foobar' on the Story model. The test builds a form on that model and supplies it with incomplete data. Why is the form considered valid by the test?

```
# models.py

class Story(models.Model):    
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    foobar = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# test.py

from django.test import TestCase
from news.models import Story
from django import forms

class StoryForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Story

class FormTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_form(self):
        post_dict = {'headline': 'Test Title'}
        form = StoryForm(post_dict)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should your `StoryForm` be inheriting from `forms.ModelForm` (not `forms.Form`)?